# How do I animate a NSWindow's size change when it gets resized by Auto Layout?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, autolayout, nswindow

Consider an `NSWindow` whose height is controlled by a set of complex constraints, and I want to have the window's resizing animated whenever the constraints cause the window to get resized.

As a simply *example*, let's just assume that the Window has no subviews, and instead of a set of complex constraints we just use a single constraint that directly controls the window's content view's height.

Now, when I change the constraint, the window gets implicitly resized. But since I do not set the window's frame myself (in the complex model I can't predict the new size!), I cannot use the animated window resize function that's commonly used for animating window resizes. So, how do I get the resize animated when Auto Layout has control over the resizing?

Here's an example in Swift. To use it, simply create a new plain "Cocoa App" project in Xcode and then replace the following function in AppDelegate:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    let view = self.window.contentView!

    // Add a height constraint to the window's view
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: view.frame.size.height)
    view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)

    // Resize the window after a brief delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {

        // Now change the constraint, which results in the window getting resized instantly.
        // But I would like the window's size change animated. How do I accomplish this?
        NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup(
            { context in
                context.duration = 0.5
                heightConstraint.constant = heightConstraint.constant + 100
            },
            completionHandler:nil
        )

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a proxy object for constraints. instead of changing the constraint's constant, set animator()'s constant. It will animate. After animation end's call `self.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()` to update the constraints.

```swift
NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ context in
    context.duration = 0.5
    context.allowsImplicitAnimation = true
    heightConstraint.animator().constant = heightConstraint.constant + 100
}, completionHandler: {
    view.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()
})
```

Comment: This works in my simple example, but what do I do if I have a complex set of constraints that I do not explicitly set like this, but where the window's size changes due to adding or removing an item from an NSStackView which in turn resizes the window due to connected constraints? In this case, the modifying factor is adding a view - how do I use an animator in such a case?

Comment: Actually, I just realized that NSViews also offer such an `animator` proxy, so instead of invoking `stackView.removeView` I can simply call `stackView.animator.removeView` to make it work. :)

Comment: Anythings that confirms to `NSAnimatablePropertyContainer` will have animator()